# One submit tag, two forms on same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am looking for the best approach to this problem. I have two search forms on the same page ( they each search a a different api for info) and I would like to have one submit button and then the relevant api is called dependent on which form has content. So I though I could specify the controller action when submitting on each form like so

```
<div class="container margin50">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3 cf formBackground">
  <h1>CoverArt Finder</h1>

  <h3>Search Movies</h3>
  <%= form_tag main_results_path, :method => "get" %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, :placeholder => 'Enter Film Name Here.....' %>

  <h1>OR<h1>

  <h3>Search Albums</h3>
  <%= form_tag album_album_results_path, :method => "get" %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, :placeholder => 'Enter Artist Name here.....' %>
  <%= submit_tag "search" %>


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Obviously this is not working as i always get the results for the movie search parameters. Do i need a conditional statement in there to recognise which form is filled in? I’m a little unsure here.

Any other info needed please ask

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to do this client side (JavaScript / jQuery) it shouldn't be much hazzle. On clicking the submit button you could check which form has an value. Some simple sudo code:

```
on submitButton click:

if formA.someValue != null
  post / submit formA
else if formB.someValue != null
  post / submit formB
```

Comment: i dont mind doing this client side, next job convert to Jquery...thanks for your assistance